# how to pass Boolean:true in vue @click event?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
@click.native="scrollTo(index,true)"
```

What I expect: Always pass `Boolean:true` into function scrollTo
What Vue react:Vue regard `true` as a name of a variable, so in scrollTo function, I get `Number:index` and `undefined` instead

How to solve it?

Comment: Can you add more pieces of your code? can't determine what's the source of the problem with the code above

Comment: @Muhammadvakili  other parts of my code are irrelative. its a syntax problem

Comment: Passing a boolean as you do above should work. I've done it before myself, e.g. `@click="submit(true)"` worked. There must be some other issue here.

Comment: See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ud0tvjn/1/) for an example where it works.

Comment: Just change @click.native="scrollTo('index',true)". It will transfer 2 params as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

my mistake.... I forgot there was another event `@touchstart="scrollTo(index)"` ahead of `@click.native="scrollTo(index,true)"` that's why I got `undefined` in scrollTo function.

Yes. vue can pass `Boolean:true` into function